# How to expand a dialogue in android on demand (e.g. a button click)

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, user-experience

I am new to android and kotlin and working on my first app which will be a library app. In the app I want to have a dialogue with some basic views (e.g. to create a database entry) which fits on one screen but I want the dialogue to be expandable on demand e.g. on a button click as additional data should be stored.

What I need is very similar to the built-in dialogue "Add new contact" of my android smartphone. First the dialogue is not scrollable and shows the most important fields on one screen but by pressing the button "add more fields" the dialogue becomes scrollable (height of two screens in portrait) and shows additional fields to save contact data.

I hope I was able to describe what I am looking for.

My first idea was to use a fragment (simple constraint layout) which will be replaced with a different fragment (ScrollView) as the user presses the "add more fields" button and retrieve the already entered information from the first fragment but I wonder if this is best practice.

Could you please give me some basic advices on how this dialogue is programmed is reality?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which extends Dialog class.

```
class AddToPlaylist(
context: Context
) : Dialog(context) {
private var playlists: List<PlaylistEntity>? = null

fun setDialogPlaylists(_playlists: List<PlaylistEntity>) {
    playlists = _playlists
}


var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
var adapter: PlaylistDialogAdapter? = null

var selectedPlaylistId = -1


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.add_to_playlist_dialog)


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPlaylists)

    adapter = PlaylistDialogAdapter(context)
    recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

    adapter?.playlistClickCallback = fun(id: Int) {
        selectedPlaylistId = id
        dismiss()
    }

    adapter?.setPlayLists(playlists!!)
}
```

In this dialog, I am using a recycler view because I will show list of playlists.
Next, I have an xml file for my dialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="12dp"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/choose_playlist"
    android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text" />


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPlaylists"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/single_playlist_item" />
```

[image: xml]

Now my dialog class is ready, I just have to create an instance where I need to use it and call show method.

```
addToPlaylistDialog = AddToPlaylist(activity as Context)
addToPlaylistDialog.show()
```

Also make use of dismiss listener to code what you want to after the dialog closes.

```
addToPlaylistDialog.setOnDismissListener {
        val playlistId: Int = addToPlaylistDialog.selectedPlaylistId
        Log.i("PLAYLISTSONGS", "Dismiss Listener called with playlistId=$playlistId")
    }
```

That should be sufficient for your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but unfortunately this is not what I asked for. Please see the text below for further information

Comment: @LIronLeaves I have a custom dialog where I wanted to use RecyclerView. You can have any layout you want there.  For example, you can simply copy your xml code from the text below to this custom dialog xml. And in the dialog class, set a click listener on the button to achieve your objective.